# Having a separate validation util for common checks

Tags: java

I am working on a project where I see the following methods wrapped in a `Util` class

```java
public static Boolean isEmpty(Collection<?> collection) {
 return (collection == null || collection.isEmpty());
}

public static Boolean isNotEmpty(Collection<?> collection) {
    return !isEmpty(collection);
}
```

Using Util method

```java
void process(List<Employee> employees) {
  if(Util.isNotEmpty(employees)) {
   // process employees
  }
}
```

Without using Util method

```java
void process(List<Employee> employees) {
  if(employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()) {
   // process employees
  }
}
```

I personally don't think there is a need for `Util` class in such case. And, a simple if block with inline multiple boolean conditions would keep it more readable and simple IMO. I'd like to hear the other perspective, when is it a real usecase for Util.

Comment: I personally think all Util classes should be renamed `MyAuthorWasLazy` because that's how they come to be. In this case it's also wrong because checking if collection is empty is not the same as checking if it's null or empty. At least they deserve better names to reflect that. Anyway your question is probably too hypothetical to be suitable for this site.

Comment: I though we were supposed to avoid copy-pasting code? How do you come to the conclusion that copy-pasting the same if-statements would be a better choice here?

Answer (score 2):

**Review**

You can take a look at what Apache Commons project has done in the [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty-java.util.Collection-) class.

Your implementation, as is the with Apache Commons too, could use improved naming. Now the user needs to go into the code and see if the method can handle null values, which wastes time. If the method checks for both null and emptiness it should be named `isNullOrEmpty`. Returning boxed boolean instead of primitive is wasteful as it creates an unnecessary object. It creates confusion as there is no compile time indication of whether the method returns null or not.

In my opinion, writing `if (isNullOrEmpty(collection))` is faster to read, easier to understand and less prone to errors than repeating `if (collection == null || collection.isEmpty())`. This difference is magnified with the negative example.

I'm not a fan of "negative names returning positive result" such as `isNotEmpty`. It creates and additional layer of confusion as I have to mentally flip the result in order to follow the code. In worst cases they result in double negatives `if (! isNotAvailble())`

As to having a generic Util-class, absolutely do not do that. They never work. If you need an utility method for checking the properties of Collections and cannot use the Apache Commons library, place it in a class dedicated for utilities dealing with Colletions. That way you have a small chance of not ending up with 1000 lines of messy unrelated static methods.

**Solution**

If you constantly end up needing this kind of low level helper methods, it is a sign that you may be using inefficient data structures. Instead of always processing `List` objects, change the code to process complex data objects that describe what the list represents with their names, methods and JavaDocs and provide the `isEmpty()` method in that class. Your example for processing employee list was so trivial and void of context that I cannot really give you a good example. Maybe something like `EmployeeSearchResult` etc. Then make it a rule to never pass null references and enofrce it with `Objects.requireNonNull(...)` assertations or similar mechanisms in external interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, this is a nullability problem. You have 3 possible states (null, empty, non-empty) and trying to wrap them into 2 states only.
This is overall code smell when trying to give null and null-object the same meaning.
Unless you have very good reason to do something like that (why 3 states? what does empty mean? what does null mean?), I suggest just avoid using nulls completely.

Imho the best practice is to remove the util class and use some kind of mechanism that does nullcheck, take your pick/combinations:

- Avoid nulls whenever possible, use "checkNotNull" aggresively at the beginning of your methods to ensure your code fails fast if that ever happens. NullPointerExceptions are sometimes nasty to figure out.
- Use `@Nullable` or `@NotNull` annotations that will help you find NPE risks through your IDE.
- Use `Optional` to signal a variable that is allowed to be null.

Comment: Using Optional in variables is abuse of the class. It was intended to provide a compile-time nullability to return values only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31923105/1047418

Comment: I do not like excessive checkNotNull or requireNotNull checks in methods. They always throw me into a tangent because they imply that the code I am looking at might produce nulls and force me to look if I need to add checks. In my opinion they should only be used in external interfaces which produce data that you don't control yourself. I would say that the suggestions to use checkNotNul is a good temporary fix for really bad quality codebases that should be removed once code quality improves. It should not be taken as general advice.

Comment: It's not in variable but input or output of the method to signal the nullability. I agree that `Optional` is the worst way to do this, that's why I put it last.

Comment: And I definitely prefer adding nullchecks anywhere when's even a remote danger of someone passing null. Even internal call if the library is big and people in the team make mistakes. When would be the time to "remove" then? You can never be safe if the code constantly evolves and I prefer that than random NPE that needs hunting down. In reality I solve if by using kotlin if I can so this is solved on the language level already.